# Point Based Clustering find the pushpin Cluster latitude longitude at any given time

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, markerclusterer

I have used the point based clustering http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Point%20Based%20Clustering

This is great for clustering. However, I am trying to find the longitude latitude of a cluster which contains first pushpin every 5 second using setInterval...obviously I am just simplifying the scenario..

```
var pushpin = pinLayer[0]; grabbing first story of the pin 
var currentClusterIndex = pushpin._clusterIndex; // get the cluster index
var currentCluster = pinLayer.GetPinByClusterIndex(currentClusterIndex);// get cluster         info
var currentLatitude = currentClusterLocation.latitude; // get latitude
var currentLongitude = currentClusterLocation.longitude; // get longitude
```

Now the latitude and longitude is correct when the map loads, but right after user interaction it's rarely correct, it's giving latitude longitude of different cluster.

Could someone possibly help with this?

Comment: To put in nutshell, how to find the lat long of the cluster that contains a certain pushpin after user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you want to do. Your code seems to indicate you want to take a pushpin that's on the map and get it's cluster index and use that to get a reference the pushpin. This will just give you a reference the pushpin you are ready have. I suspect you want to get the data for the pushpin which you can easily do by passing the cluster index into the GetDataByClusterIndex method. This will return an array of all the raw data that is in cluster. You can then grab the item you want and get it's original coordinate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ricky!

I am not trying to get the info of the pin, as you mentioned I already have that either though the methods you have described or through the original source.

Anyway, what I want to do is, for a particular pushpin I would like to know the cluster lat-long..not the original lat-long of the pushpin. Now using the code similar to one above, I do get the lat-long of cluster correctly when the map loads and clusters for the first time, but once the user interacts with the map and I try to do the same thing, the cluster information including lat-long is off.

Comment: This image might help you understand my issue: 
[IMG]http://i40.tinypic.com/2hi0y1i.jpg[/IMG]

As you could see clusterIndex 8 has 4 pushpins as cluster, but their clusterIndex are 8, 12, 12, 16 rather than being 8 for all as expected.